# Python BeautifulSoup searching

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Is there a way to find a single div with more classes? Div classes are:

> class="srp-main-content clearfix srp-main-content--flex".

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to search by many classes you need to use `array` syntax, `{'class': []}`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="srp-main-content clearfix srp-main-content--flex">
    Hello
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
text = soup.find('div', {'class':
            ['srp-main-content', 'srp-main-content--flex', 'clearfix']}).text
print(text)
```

**Output**

```
Hello
```

Comment: @ZenWoR click the check next to his answer to close the question